# How to add website icon for the safari

Tags: html, safari, icons

I am trying to add the website icon for the safari. The icon show up on "Add to home screen". However, it does not show up when I am trying to add it to favorite or bookmark. (It show up in simulator..)

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/static/images/logo-ios.png"/>
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="/static/images/ios.png"/>
<link rel="apple-touch-icon"  sizes="114x114" href="/static/images/logo-ios.png"/>
<link rel="apple-touch-icon"  sizes="144×144" href="/static/images/logo-ios.png"/>
```

I also have manifest.json for the android which seems not affect anything in safari

Answer (score 0):

Your logo-ios.png file should be 150x150 pixels and it should also be named apple-touch-icon.png.  I'm not sure the file name is important. But I believe the size is.